# JavaScript security issue

Tags: javascript, security, this

I wanna know how the following function set 'this' element and fetch the array cell out? please.

```js
//my secure code
var priv = ['item-0','item-1'];
var api = {push: function(x){priv.push(x)}}

api.store = function(i,x){priv[i] = x}

//the attaker script
var result;
api.store('push',function(){result = this[0]});
api.push();

//the result is cell 0 of private array
//how?
//if i change the 'push' parameter then the result is empty!
document.write(result)
```

Comment: The `this` keyword may have different meanings depending on the context. You have not declared the `result` variable anywhere, so by default it has the global scope, that is why it becomes available outside the function. Could you provide more details about your problem

Comment: @CROSP I have some critical content, and I want to keep them safe. 
one of my friends send me this code and I realize he can access to private variables, using my API objects.

Comment: @easa If an attacker can execute arbitrary code in the same environment, you usually have already lost. What exactly are you trying to protect?

Comment: Yes, that's right. there's an API I'm working on @Bergi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens is that `api.store('push',function(){result = this[0]});` overrides the `push` method of the `priv` array. That means that after this line `push`is no longer the push method that javascript natively provides but the attackers custom function, which is `function(){result = this[0]}`. Now, when you call `api.push()` it calls `priv.push(x)` which was overridden. Since `push` is called on an object, `this` is bound to the object, which is `priv` (more on that [in the MDN article on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). Therefore, `result = this[0]` is equal to `result = priv[0]` and result will contain the first array entry.

Comment: I can not understand how it was overridden? In which line? how?

Comment: `api.store('push',function(){result = this[0]});` calls `api.store = function(i,x){priv[i] = x}` . Here, `i` is push and x is the function your attacker passed. This means you are effectively executing `priv["push"] = function(){result = this[0]}` which is equal to `priv.push = function(){result = this[0]}` (hence, overriding the `push` method).